# Disable JS positioning of JQuery UI dialog

Tags: css, jquery-ui, position, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to disable the JS auto-positioning of a JQuery UI dialog() widget, so that I can position using CSS (which is much more responsive for positioning elements).

I know I can do a positional reset like this:

```
top: auto !important; /* for normal browsers */
left: auto !important;
top: initial !important; /* for chrome */
left: initial !important;
```

…but it's ugly, & seems like overkill.  JQuery UI's API is giving me nil.

**Is it possible to prevent JQuery UI from assigning a `top` and `left` css property to a UI Dialog widget?**

Answer (score 1):

The "position" option seems pretty comprehensive to me, and I don't know of a documented way to position the dialog with pure non-hacky, non-!important CSS.

Having said that, here's a hacky, undocumented, bound-to-fail-in-future way to do what you asked for. It involves overriding the internal `_position` method.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/2puF8/1/

HTML: `<div id="d">hey hey</div>`

CSS:

```
.dialog {
    position: absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
}
```

JS:

```
var d = $('#d');

d.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    dialogClass: 'dialog'
});

d.data('uiDialog')._position = $.noop;

d.dialog('open');

// if you want it for all dialogs:
// $.ui.dialog.prototype._position = $.noop;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, at least not with JQuery UI v1.10.2